# C/C++ fast absolute difference between two series

Tags: c++, performance, time-series, difference

i am interested in generating efficient c/c++ code to get the differences between two time series.
More precise: The time series values are stored as uint16_t arrays with fixed and equal length == 128.

**I am good with a pure c as well as a pure c++ implementation. My code examples are in c++**

My intentions are:

```
Let A,B and C be discrete time series of length l with a value-type of uint16_t.
Vn[n<l]: Cn = |An - Bn|;
```

What i can think of in pseudo code:

```
for index i:
 if a[i] > b[i]:
    c[i] = a[i] - b[i]
 else:
    c[i] = b[i] - a[i]
```

Or in c/c++

```
for(uint8_t idx = 0; idx < 128; idx++){
    c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] - b[i] : b[i] - a[i];
}
```

But i really dont like the if/else statement in the loop.
I am okay with looping - this can be unrolled by the compiler.
Somewhat like:

```
void getBufDiff(const uint16_t (&a)[], const uint16_t (&b)[], uint16_t (&c)[]) {
#pragma unroll 16
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] - b[i] : b[i] - a[i];
    }
#end pragma
}
```

What i am looking for is a 'magic code' which speeds up the if/else and gets me the absolute difference between the two unsigned values.

I am okay with a +/- 1 precision (In case this would allow some bit-magic to happen). I am also okay with changing the data-type to get faster results. And i am also okay with dropping the loop for something else.

So something like:

```
void getBufDiff(const uint16_t (&a)[], const uint16_t (&b)[], uint16_t (&c)[]) {
#pragma unroll 16
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        c[i] = magic_code_for_abs_diff(a[i],b[i]);
    }
#end pragma
}
```

Did try XORing the two values. Gives proper results only for one of the cases.

**EDIT 2:**

Did a quick test on different approaches on my Laptop.

For 250000000 entrys this is the performance (256 rounds):

```
c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] - b[i] : b[i] - a[i];  ~500ms
c[i] = std::abs(a[i] - b[i]);                    ~800ms
c[i] = ((a[i] - b[i]) + ((a[i] - b[i]) >> 15)) ^ (i >> 15) ~425ms
uint16_t tmp = (a[i] - b[i]); c[i] = tmp * ((tmp > 0) - (tmp < 0)); ~600ms
uint16_t ret[2] = { a[i] - b[i], b[i] - a[i] };c[i] = ret[a[i] < b[i]] ~900ms
c[i] = ((a[i] - b[i]) >> 31 | 1) * (a[i] - b[i]); ~375ms
c[i] = ((a[i] - b[i])) ^ ((a[i] - b[i]) >> 15) ~425ms
```

Comment: Do you want generic code, or is for instance AVX (Intel-only) ok? Did you look at the asm generated by your compiler?

Comment: Please note that there is no such language as "C/C++", only the two *very* different languages C and C++. The function you show is not C, so please don't tag tag language.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Codebase is targeted for ARM M7. Pseudo ASM is good though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am good with a native C implementation aswell!

Comment: And I assume you have tried something like `std::abs(a[i] - b[i])` already?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I could image it beeing pretty slow. But no, i did not do any benchmarks.

Comment: First always try all "standard" alternatives, with optimized builds, and benchmark. If you don't have a base measurement to go from, how do you know if what optimizations you can come up with is better or worse?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are correct. Did a quick test on my laptop (MS Visual Studio C++). std::abs is outperformed by an average of around 40% by the if/else loop by targeting a 250000000 elements series with random values for 256 times.

Comment: [Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-integer-absolute-value-abs-without-branching/) give a hack that does not need branching (shown below by @freakish).

Comment: Fast abs (under two complement integers) can be implemented as `(x + (x >> N)) ^ (x >> N)` where `N` is the size of int - 1, i.e. 15 in your case. That's a possible implementation of std::abs. Still you can try it

Comment: Gcc already vectorizes your ?: version...

Comment: @freakish Thank you. Tried it - ist faster than branching for sure.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Optimization is O3. Did not dig into the disassembly yet.

Comment: Does `#include <arm_neon.h>` work on your system?  If it does, you could use NEON intrinsics to write SIMD code doing up to 8 subtractions at once: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dht0002/a/Introducing-NEON/Developing-for-NEON/Intrinsics
The sketch is: (1) load 8 values from `a`,  (2) load 8 values from `b`, (3) subtract, (4) store 8 values to `c`.  Do that 16 times and all 128 elements are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to let the compiler see the conditional lane-selection pattern for SIMD instructions like this (pseudo code):

```
// store a,b to SIMD registers
for(0 to 32)
   a[...] = input[...]
   b[...] = input2[...]

// single type operation, easily parallelizable
for(0 to 32)
   vector1[...] = a[...] - b[...]

// single type operation, easily parallelizable
// maybe better to compute b-a to decrease dependency to first step
// since a and b are already in SIMD registers
for(0 to 32)
   vector2[...] = -vector1[...]

// single type operation, easily parallelizable
// re-use a,b registers, again
for(0 to 32)
   vector3[...] = a[...] < b[...]

// x84 architecture has SIMD instructions for this
// operation is simple, no other calculations inside, just 3 inputs, 1 out
// all operands are registers (at least should be, if compiler works fine)
for(0 to 32)
   vector4[...] = vector3[...] ? vector2[...]:vetor1[...]
```

If you write your benchmark codes, I can compare this with other solutions. But it wouldn't matter for good compilers (or good compiler flags) that do same thing automatically for the first benchmark code in question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a good candidate for SIMD.  GCC can do it automatically, here is a simplified example: https://godbolt.org/z/36nM8bYYv

```
void absDiff(const uint16_t* a, const uint16_t* b, uint16_t* __restrict__ c)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] - b[i];
}
```

Note that I added `__restrict__` to enable autovectorization, otherwise the compiler has to assume your arrays may overlap and it isn't safe to use SIMD (because some writes could change future reads in the loop).

I simplified it to just 16 at a time, and removed the absolute value for the sake of illustration.  The generated assembly is:

```
    vld1.16 {q9}, [r0]!
    vld1.16 {q11}, [r1]!
    vld1.16 {q8}, [r0]
    vld1.16 {q10}, [r1]
    vsub.i16        q9, q9, q11
    vsub.i16        q8, q8, q10
    vst1.16 {q9}, [r2]!
    vst1.16 {q8}, [r2]
    bx      lr
```

That means it loads 8 integers at once from `a`, then from `b`, repeats that once, then does 8 subtracts at once, then again, then stores 8 values twice into `c`.  Many fewer instructions than without SIMD.

Of course it requires benchmarking to see if this is actually faster on your system (after you add back the absolute value part, I suggest using your `?:` approach which does not defeat autovectorization), but I expect it will be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

> Fast `abs` (under two complement integers) can be implemented as `(x + (x >> N)) ^ (x >> N)` where N is the size of int - 1, i.e. 15 in your case. That's a possible implementation of `std::abs`. Still you can try it

– answer by [freakish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645551/freakish)

Answer (score 1):

Since you write "I am okay with a +/- 1 precision", you can use a XOR-solution: instead of `abs(x)`, do `x ^ (x >> 15)`. This will give an off-by-1 result for negative values.

If you want to calculate the correct result even for negative values, use the other answer (with `x >> 15` correction).

In any case, this XOR-trick only works if overflow is impossible. The compiler can't replace `abs` by code which uses XOR because of that.